# getting error while submitting form with ajax in code igniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i am submitting a form in code igniter using jquery validate..
but i am getting error in CONSOLE

http://localhost:88/mlmm/index.php/index/[object%20RadioNodeList] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

but i checked my action is correct

http://localhost:88/mlmm/index.php/index/submit

dont know what replaces /submit with /[object%20RadioNodeList]

can any body help me

this is my js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#register_f").validate({
                    rules: {
                        "enroler": {
                            required: true,
                        },  
                    },
            messages: {
                enroler: "Your Enroller's ID",
                sponser: "Your Sponsor's ID",
            },

                    //perform an AJAX post to ajax.php
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                     $(".loader").show();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: form.action,
                        cache: true,
                        type: form.method,
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                         if(response!=0)
                         {
                         $(".loader").hide();
                         }
                        }            
                    });
                }                
                });

</script>
```

http://antbdevelopers.in/register.html

Comment: Provide you JS code - you are submitting to a wrong URL, I guess you are appending some object to the URL string

Comment: i updated the question with js code

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(form.action)` ? My guess is this is causing the issue. You could try `url: form.attr('action')` instead.